# How to set a layout on top of a ViewPager widget in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-widget

I want to have a layout constantly on top of everything and visible all the time, however, once I swipe to the next element in the ViewPager, the FrameLayout is getting behind the ViewPager.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/videosViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

    </androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2>

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/preview_display_layout"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"

            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="216dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

        </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried to place a button instead of and on top of the FrameLayout and, guess what, the button remains on top of everything without going behind the ViewPager after each sroll.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/videosViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">


    </androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="197dp"
        android:layout_height="286dp">

    </Button>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/preview_display_layout"
        android:layout_width="197dp"
        android:layout_height="286dp"

        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="216dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Here is my code in MainActivity

```
    private ViewPager2 videosViewPager;
    private SurfaceView previewDisplayView;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getContentViewLayoutResId());

        previewDisplayView = new SurfaceView(this);
        setupPreviewDisplayView();


         videosViewPager = findViewById(R.id.videosViewPager);

        List<VideoItem> videoItems = new ArrayList<>();

        VideoItem life = new VideoItem();
        String path = "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+ R.raw.video;
        life.videoURL = Uri.parse(path);
   
        videoItems.add(life);

        VideoItem rest = new VideoItem();
        String path2 = "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+ R.raw.video1;
        rest.videoURL = Uri.parse(path);
  
        videoItems.add(rest);

        videosViewPager.setAdapter(new VideoAdapter(videoItems));
}

    private void setupPreviewDisplayView() {
        previewDisplayView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ViewGroup viewGroup = findViewById(R.id.preview_display_layout);
        viewGroup.addView(previewDisplayView);

        previewDisplayView
                .getHolder()
                .addCallback(
                        new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                                processor.getVideoSurfaceOutput().setSurface(holder.getSurface());
                                Log.d("Surface","Surface Created");

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
                                onPreviewDisplaySurfaceChanged(holder, format, width, height);
                                
                                Log.d("Surface","Surface Changed");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                                processor.getVideoSurfaceOutput().setSurface(null);
                                Log.d("Surface","Surface destroy");
                            }

                        });

    }
```

I guess my issue is in adding SurfaceView(previewDisplayView)in ViewGroup.
What can I do to make the previewDisplayView get always on top of everything? By the way, I tried bringToFront(), but after a swipe the previewDisplayLayout is automatically going behind the ViewPager.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `android:elevation` property ? I think it is what you're looking for,
Hope will help

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your response! No, unfortunately, it doesn't work. The problem is that the ViewPager widget always gets on top of everything after I swipe to the next element in the ViewPager.